# How do I properly use Svelte file naming conventions (+page.svelte, etc.) to import component directories

Tags: javascript, html, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

i am just starting to use svelte and am confused with how to properly structure the project. As an example I want to seperate the webpage into Header, Body, and Footer sections.

By default the root page is called `+page.svelte`. I created a `+layout.svelte` and added `<slot/>`.

If I want to have a folder for each component the file structure will look something like:

```
- routes
-- Footer
---- +page.svelte
-- Header
---- +page.svelte
-- Main
---- +page.svelte
-- +layout.svelte
```

Each `+page.svelte` looks something like:

```
<section id="Header">
    Goodbye World OR Hello World OR Something else for MAIN section
</section>
```

And `+layout.svelte`

```
<script>
    import Main from "./Main.svelte";
    import Header from "./Header.svelte";
    import Footer from "./Footer.svelte";
</script>


<section>
    <header>
        <Header/>
    </header>

    <section>
        <Main/>
    </section>

    <footer>
        <Footer/>
    </footer>
</section>
```

My import statement are wrong, but aside from that, in general how do I ago about structuring components in a svelte project? How do I import them? Thanks!

EDIT:

just changed the import statements, in general I would still like to know how to structure svelte projects

```
<script>
    import Main from "./Main/+page.svelte";
    import Header from "./Header/+page.svelte";
    import Footer from "./Footer/+page.svelte";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each directory in your `routes` directory represents a new route, so you don't want to create a new directory for `Header` (which would result in a new route `https://example.com/Header`) and components of that nature.

You could put the `Header.svelte` and `Footer.svelte` components directly in the `routes` directory since they are only used there. If you have components that are reused throughout the application you could put them in e.g. `src/lib/components` instead.

```bash
routes/
├─ about/
├─ blog/
├─ +layout.svelte
├─ +page.svelte
├─ Header.svelte
├─ Footer.svelte
```

```html
<!-- routes/+layout.svelte -->

<script>
    import Header from "./Header.svelte";
    import Footer from "./Footer.svelte";
</script>

<Header/>

<slot />

<Footer />
```

Comment: If I don't have a +page.svelte inside of the routes folder I get a notification that the root route could not be found, however using +layout.svelte without it still works fine. I do not have a lib/components directory so I will make one and do as you suggested, thanks!