# Where to put svelte default layout template components

Tags: layout, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

**INTRODUCTION**

In svelte, we know that default layout is store on

`src/routes/+layout.svelte`

and I also know some people use group layout

`src/route/(app)/+layout.svelte`

But that's not what I'm looking for since I only use a single layout.

**EXPLANATION**

Assuming the template contain navigation, breadcrumb, footer, widget & etc.

To code all inside this single `+layout.svelte`, it will ended up with thousand line of codes inside a single file. I would like to componentize each of them into a single file and use them inside the main `+layout.svelte` file. But the problem is. Where to place it?

**WORKAROUND**

Currently, I using the following scheme for my layout template

All the componentize layout template is store on

`src/lib/templates`

And inside that `templates` directory, I have the following scheme

`src/lib/templates/breadcrumb/ all the .scss, .svelte, .ts related to breadcrumb`

`src/lib/templates/footer/ all the .scss, .svelte, .ts related to footer`

`src/lib/templates/the rest of my template/ all the .scss, .svelte, .ts related to the rest of my template`

And using in `+layout.svelte` as follow

```
// src/routes/+layout.svelte

<script>
    import Navigation from '@templates/navigation/Navigation.svelte';
    ...
</script>

<div id="app">
    <Navigation />

    <main>
        <slot />
    </main>
</div>
```

Please note that `@templates` is a resolver alias

**QUESTION**

1. Is that this question is opinion based? If yes, could anyone suggest me your opinion on how you build the template for your application? Since I search for documentation and found nothing.
2. What is the best practice for layout templating in svelte

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did not check the documentation, but my head tells me the Svelte documentation or the learning site recommends creating the components in the same folder where they are used, as long as they are only consumed in that folder.  If the component is needed elsewhere, then it goes inside `lib`.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But the `+layout.svelte` is placed on `src/routes`. Doing so, that component can be accessible by `localhost:5173/ that component`. And entering that URL will give me a blank page since there's no `+page.svelte` created on `that component` directory. If I'm creating it like this `src/route/that component.svelte`, my `src/route` directory will be bloated with much of `.ts`, `.scss`, `.svelte` files. Since to making a complete template required more than 1 components to be use. Example: `navbar`, `footer`, `breadcrumb` &etc

Comment: I think I understand, and my answer still stands:  If `src/routes/+layout.svelte` uses `NavBar.svelte`, `Footer.svelte` + 10 others, then `src/routes/` will have `+layout.svelte` and 10 more `.svelte` files.  If you have stores or others utils only used by `+layout.svelte` or related components, then these will also be found in the same folder.

Comment: Additional notes for @José Ramírez answer for reference: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74944173/12865265)